# Can we use same AWS instances M10 for both application Deployment and MongoDB Atlas cluster?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-atlas

I need to set up the AWS instance and MongoDB atlas but got some doubts like can we use the same AWS instances(tier) for both my Node application and MongoDB atlas?

MongoDB atlas recommended M10 instance type but I want to use free tier from AWS t2.micro. so how can I combine this, or is it possible to use M10 for both?

Comment: Do you mean to use a single instance for both application and the MongoDB atlas?

Comment: M10 instance type seems to be belonging to MongoDB Atlas only. It is a managed service, so It would not be possible to host your node application within that instance.

Comment: No, you can't. (and you really shouldn't).

Comment: @Technowise, Okay, then it will charge only at MongoDB atlas right? not in AWS.

Comment: Okay @TomSlabbaert